# How to resolve "MMC cannot initialize snap-in."

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, mmc

Windows 2012 R2. I have at least two snap ins which will not load, eventviewer and DFS management.

I have tried;

1. SFC scannow
2. DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
3. Delete registry key/reboot.
4. Deleted files in %AppData%\Microsoft\MMC

None of these worked, although the delete registry key trick was supposed to recreate the key automatically, it did not. I reloaded the .reg file.

Everything seems to work well on the server, I can access the event viewer from another server, and do not see any errors.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Delete the files for those consoles in %AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\MMC.

Comment: Forgot to mention I had deleted files in %AppData%\Microsoft\MMC. I will add it above.